# How to extract the text from the search results of duckduckgo using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, duckduckgo

I am trying to get the link descriptions of duckduck of search results using the following:

```
results=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='links']/div/div/div[2]")
description=[]
for result in results:
  description.append(result.text)
```

I am getting the error 'list' object has no attribute 'text'. I was able to use a similar method to get the search result titles, but for some reason I am unable to extract the text from this particular xpath.

Comment: What happen when you try to write the desctiption[] in to console?

Comment: Can you post the full error message and part of the HTML that you are trying to read?

Comment: They list items showed up as blank

Comment: Example of url passed to browser.get(url) : https://duckduckgo.com/?q=hello&t=h_

Comment: what are you trying to extract on this url @michael ? your xpath might be referring to an object rather than list of objects

Comment: @michael , would you mind to provide the whole code? I would like to see the website to simulate the problem

Comment: I am trying to extract the descriptions shown under the title and link of each page. All I need to know is what is the correct xpath to be using as the one I am using doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @michael Please don't change the question based on which you have received well researched answers. Once you receive canonical answers changing the question can make all the existing answers invalid and may not be useful to future readers. If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question. StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out. For the time being I have reverted back the question to it's initial state.

Answer (score 3):

To extract the link descriptions of the search results from `DuckDuckGo` you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *visibility of all elements located* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://duckduckgo.com/')
  search_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q")))
  search_box.send_keys("Selenium")
  search_box.submit()
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='links']/div/div/div[2]")))
  for ele in elements:
      print(ele.text)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  What is Selenium? Selenium automates browsers.That's it! What you do with that power is entirely up to you. Primarily, it is for automating web applications for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to just that.
  Selenium is a mineral found in the soil. Selenium naturally appears in water and some foods. While people only need a very small amount, selenium plays a key role in the metabolism.. Why do people ...
  Selenium is a chemical element with symbol Se and atomic number 34. It is a nonmetal (more rarely considered a metalloid) with properties that are intermediate between the elements above and below in the periodic table, sulfur and tellurium, and also has similarities to arsenic.
  Selenium is a trace mineral found naturally in the soil that also appears in certain high-selenium foods, and there are even small amounts in water.. Selenium is an extremely vital mineral for the human body as it increases immunity, takes part in antioxidant activity that defends against free radical damage and inflammation, and plays a key role in maintaining a healthy metabolism.
  Introduction. Selenium is a trace element that is naturally present in many foods, added to others, and available as a dietary supplement. Selenium, which is nutritionally essential for humans, is a constituent of more than two dozen selenoproteins that play critical roles in reproduction, thyroid hormone metabolism, DNA synthesis, and protection from oxidative damage and infection [].
  Selenium is an essential trace mineral that is important for many bodily processes, including cognitive function, a healthy immune system, and fertility in both men and women.
  Your body relies on selenium, an important mineral, for many of its basic functions, from reproduction to fighting infection. The amount of selenium in different foods depends on the amount of ...
  Overview Information Selenium is a mineral. It is taken into the body in water and foods. People use it for medicine. Most of the selenium in the body comes from the diet. The amount of selenium ...
  Selenium WebDriver. The biggest change in Selenium recently has been the inclusion of the WebDriver API. Driving a browser natively as a user would either locally or on a remote machine using the Selenium Server it marks a leap forward in terms of browser automation.
  Downloads. Below is where you can find the latest releases of all the Selenium components. You can also find a list of previous releases, source code, and additional information for Maven users (Maven is a popular Java build tool).
  ```

Comment: Unable to get the desired results. I updated the question with the new code included

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create a for loop for the empty list... try using this code:

```
results=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='links']/div/div/div[2]")

description=[]

for result in results:
    description.append(result.text)
```

Example:
To test this I simply typed 'hmm' in DuckDuckGo so the URL is https://duckduckgo.com/?q=hmm&t=h_&ia=web

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://duckduckgo.com/?q=hmm&t=h_&ia=web')

results=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='links']/div/div/div[2]")

description=[]

for result in results:
    description.append(result.text)

print(description[0])
print(' ')
print(description[1])
print(' ')
print(description[2])
```

Output:

> HMM to Develop "New-GAUS 2020"... HMM Holds 'PSA-Hyundai Pusan N... HMM Names New VLCC, 'Universal... 2019 New Year's Message; The HMM's Future Plan; HMM Blueprint for the Year 202... HMM signed the formal contract...
>
> Hmm definition, (used typically to express thoughtful absorption, hesitation, doubt, or perplexity.) See more.
>
> 2 � used to emphasize that one has asked a question and is awaiting an answer But tell Santa the truth now, what's the most important part to a little boy or girl? The box

The search results:

[image: Search Results]

Comment: Note: The question was edited... it previously had a for loop for the empty list

Comment: I removed the loop, which was non essential. However, I still experience the same problem with obtaining the descriptions