# How to handle the error out of a try loop using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, webdriverwait, duckduckgo

I'd like to run a search with selenium and click the "more results" button at the end of a DDG search.

The DDG search no longer shows the button when it's shown all the results for a query.

I'd like to exit out of the try loop in the case where there is no button.

I'll share what I'm trying now. I also tried earlier these two options: `If len(button_element) > 0: button_element.click()` and I tried `If button_element is not None: button_element.click()`.

I'd like the solution to use Selenium so it shows the browser because it's helpful for debugging

This is my code with a reproducible example:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    browser = webdriver.Chrome()        
    browser.get("https://duckduckgo.com/")
    search = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
    search.send_keys("this is a search" + Keys.RETURN)
    html = browser.page_source

    try:
        button_element = browser.find_element_by_class_name('result--more__btn')

        try:
            button_element.click()
        except SystemExit:
            print("No more pages")

    except:
        pass
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me https://codeshare.io/5oZlep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click the <kbd>More Results</kbd> button at the end of a [duckduckgo](/questions/tagged/duckduckgo) search results using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
  from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://duckduckgo.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys("this is a search" + Keys.RETURN)
  while True:
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.result--more__btn"))).click()
            print("Clicked on More Results button")
        except TimeoutException:
            print("No more More Results button")
            break
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Clicked on More Results button
  Clicked on More Results button
  Clicked on More Results button
  Clicked on More Results button
  Clicked on More Results button
  No more More Results button
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to extract the text from the search results of duckduckgo using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55017612/how-to-extract-the-text-from-the-search-results-of-duckduckgo-using-selenium-pyt/55018727#55018727)

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for. Can I user this with browser.get?

Comment: @tadon11Aaa `driver` is a variable of type`WebDriver`, you can name it anything, e.g. `browser`, `browser1`, `browser2`, etc

Comment: Great, can you add your imports to your answer? This is resulting in NameError: name 'TimeoutException' is not defined

Comment: @tadon11Aaa My bad, I should have added the imports as well. Now updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pure HTML version of DDG, on URL `https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=`. This way you can use pure `requests`/`beautifulsoup` method and get all pages easily:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


q = '"centre of intelligence"'
url = 'https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q={q}'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(q=q), headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

while True:
    for t, a, s in zip(soup.select('.result__title'), soup.select('.result__a'), soup.select('.result__snippet')):
        print(t.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))
        print(a['href'])
        print(s.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))
        print('-' * 80)

    f = soup.select_one('.nav-link form')
    if not f:
        break

    data = {}
    for i in f.select('input'):
        if i['type']=='submit':
            continue
        data[i['name']] = i.get('value', '')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post('https://duckduckgo.com' + f['action'], data=data, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
```

Prints:

```
Centre Of Intelligence - Home | Facebook
https://www.facebook.com/Centre-Of-Intelligence-937637846300833/
Centre Of Intelligence . 73 likes. Non-profit organisation. Facebook is showing information to help you better understand the purpose of a Page.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
centre of intelligence | English examples in context | Ludwig
https://ludwig.guru/s/centre+of+intelligence
(Glasgow was "the centre of the intelligence of England" according to the Grand Duke Alexis, who attended the launch of his father Tsar Alexander II's steam yacht there in 1880).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Chinese scientists who studied bats in Aus at centre of intelligence ...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UhcFXXzf2hc
Intelligence agencies are looking into two Chinese scientists in a bid to learn the true origin of COVID-19. Two Chinese scientists who studied live bats in...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

... and so on.
```

Comment: How do I make this show the browser like the original code?

Comment: Edited the question to include the requirement that the solution shows the browser

Comment: @tadon11Aaa BeautifulSoup doesn't use browser at all. To debug a page, you can do `print(soup)` or `print(soup.prettify())`. You can redirect this output to file and then open it in the browser manually.

Comment: Thanks! I'll edit my answer to specify that I'd like to do this with selenium

Comment: @tadon11Aaa I don't have experience with Selenium, but use URL `https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=<your keyword>`. It doesn't use javascript so navigating it would be easier I think.

Answer (score 0):

Use WebDriverWait to wait until there is an more button

```python
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 15) # 15 seconds timeout 
wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'result--more__btn')))
```

This example code clicks the more button until there is no more button anymore
for chrome replace **firefox** with **chrome**

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

browser = webdriver.Firefox()        
browser.get("https://duckduckgo.com/")
search = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys("this is a search" + Keys.RETURN)

while True:
    try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 15) # 15 seconds timeout
        wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'result--more__btn')))

        button_element = browser.find_element_by_class_name('result--more__btn')
        button_element.click()
    except:
        break
```

Comment: My program keeps waiting for the new **more button** so it clicks the **more button** until  it cant find a **more button** in **15 seconds**
And it does that infinitely

Comment: So you have to wait for the timeout because maybe there will a button be generated. But I think you can lower the timeout from 15 to 3 seconds.

Comment: you cant run code in codeshare just copy it into your editor